# pass list(strings) as a terraform variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp

While defining my module, I do this:

```
module "activate_alarms" {
  source = "../_modules/aws/.."
  config = module.config
  alarm_arns = ["arn:aws:cloudwatch:eu-central-123:test-alarm"]
}
```

```
variable "alarm_arns" {
  type = list(string)
}
```

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "processing_lambda" {
  filename         = data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_path
  function_name    = local.processing_lambda_name
  handler          = "enable_disable_alarms.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_base64sha256
  role             = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn

  runtime = "python3.9"
  tags = var.config.tags
  environment {
    variables = {
      alarm_arns = local.alarm_arns
    }
  }
}
```

However, I get an error:

```
 Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on ../_modules/aws/enable_disable_alarms/processing_lambda.tf line 20, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "processing_lambda":
│   20:     variables = {
│   23:       alarm_arns = local.alarm_arns
│   30:     }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.alarm_arns is a list of string, known only after apply
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "variables": element "alarm_arns": string required.
```

What's the correct way to pass a list of strings?

Edit:

```
locals {
  config = var.config

  alarm_arns = "${var.alarm_arns}"
}
```

Comment: What is `local.alarm_arns`? Its not defined in your code.

Comment: check edited qs @Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass `list(string)` directly as `environment` into lambda. You have to make it into string first, e.g.:

```
  environment {
    variables = {
      alarm_arns = jsonencode(var.alarm_arns)
    }
  }
```

Then in your lambda you would have to convert it back to list of strings according to your programming language.

Comment: why can't we directly pass lists tho?

Comment: @x89 Because list is not a string.